# Redirect everything in a subfolder to another folder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to get the following group of urls to redirect to a single subfolder. I would like it to be one rule to deal with all of the urls because i will have a bunch more.

- mysite.com/subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/1102000/albums.php?albumId=175339
- mysite.com/subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/1107778/albums.php
- mysite.com/subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/1107778/albums.php?albumId=
- mysite.com/subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/1110600/1101254/albums.php?albumId=175339
- mysite.com/subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/1113010/1113010-BRO.pdf?url=1113010-BRO&last=1113010&rest=Images/safety&ext=.pdf

All above url's Redirect to:

mysite.com/store/safety/

I have tried

RewriteRule ^subfolder/attachmentlibrary/safety/(.*)$ /store/safety/$1 [R=301,L]

But i can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to RewriteRules

Answer (score 0):

Create a `/subfolder/.htaccess` with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^attachmentlibrary/safety/(.*)$ /store/safety/$1? [NC,R=302,L]
```